# TabLayout measuring

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm using TabLayout for creating my tabs. The problem is that when trying to measure it in the code it gives me 0 width. Now, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or what exactly the system means by 0 width.

What I need is to measure TabLayout width after it was inflated. I want to make it scrollable only if it's wider than screen width and center it if it has smaller width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.yrs.androidltx.features.adapterviews.viewpager.WithViewPagerActivity"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

After checking with this piece of code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();

   TabLayout.Tab tab1 = null;
   View customView = null;
   try {

       int width = tabLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
       Log.i(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Tab Layout measured width: " + width);

       tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
       customView = tab1.getCustomView();
       int tabWidth = customView.getWidth();
       Log.i(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Tab 0 width: " + tabWidth);

       int tabMeasuredWidth = customView.getMeasuredWidth();
       Log.i(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Tab 0 measured width: " + tabMeasuredWidth);

   } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
       Log.e(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Exception: NullPointer on TabLayout");

   } catch (Exception ex) {
       Log.e(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Exception: Debug it!");

   } finally {
       Log.i(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Report Tab: " + tab1);
       Log.i(BuildConfig.DEV_TAG, "Report Tab (custom view): " + customView);
   }
}
```

I get zeroes and Null Pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure view after they are inflated and measured. Use `ViewTreeObserver` for that:

```
tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            tabLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        //measure your views
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: I also tried with a .post() method and it seems to be working. ViewTreeObserver is new to me. I'll investigate it further and test your code.